# Can a magnetic or electric field deflect subatomic particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, magnetic-fields

I always wondered if the subatomic particles can be deflected by a magnetic or electric field. Basically I am asking the viability of the typical "Force Field" in movies.

Comment: That is essentially how old-style TVs worked. As well as particle colliders in physics labs. But movie science is 99.999% nonsense. If you consider the Sun a typical homicidal alien, the Earth has a pretty nifty magnetic shield against death-rays.

Comment: Have a look at all these bubble chamber pictures of particles turning in a magnetic field http://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCWebsite/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Only charged particles can be deflected: electrons, protons, and other charged hadrons and mesons.  Light and X-ray can't.

Comment: Net neutral particles with magnetic moments can also be affected, though less effectively. For example the Stern–Gerlach experiment.